# Fast distinct list of elements in an array python

Tags: python, arrays, distinct, element

I need to speed up the time to count the distinct elements in this code and I'm not really sure how to do a faster count.

```
def process_columns(columns):
    with open(columns, 'r') as src:
        data = csv.reader(src, delimiter ='\t', skipinitialspace = False)
        category = []
        group = columns.split("/")
        group = group[-1].split(".")
        if group[0] in ["data_1", "data_2"]:
            for row in data:
                if row[0] not in category:
                    category.append(row[0])
             message = "\t%d distinct elements from %ss" % (len(category), group[0])
        print message
```

Comment: @Coldspeed why appending to a list to convert to set afterwards ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Nope, not needed. Actually mentioned it only as a quick-fix to OP's existing code. But there are better ways...

Comment: @Coldspeed we're waiting for a nice answer from you as you know how to cook them :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Haha, dinner is served. vv

Answer (score 2):

A master method to count distinct elements in a python array is :

```
array = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6]
n_elts = len(set(array))
print(n_elts)
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: how can OP adapt your method to his/her code? note: this is a _list_ not an array.

Comment: this code is correct for all iterables list or array .... ;), here it is a list right but if array = np.array([1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6]) it is correct.

Comment: @glegoux How would OP go about making the change? What variable is to be converted? Etc.

Comment: @Coldspeed I let you this privilege to precise that in your right answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without much knowledge on your data, here's a quick way to maintain a set of unique words for your groups, using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def process_columns(columns):
    categories = defaultdict(set) # initialises a default dict with values as sets
    with open(columns, 'r') as src:
        data = csv.reader(src, delimiter ='\t', skipinitialspace = False)
        group = columns.split("/")[-1].split('.')

        for row in data:
            categories[group[0]].update(row[0])       

        for k in categories:
            message = "\t%d distinct elements from %ss" % (len(categories[k]), k)
           print message
```

Comment: I think `collections.Counter` would be even better: `categories[group[0]].update(data)`, no loop. but nice enough, OP will find that usefully adapted to his/her case.

Comment: Counter is fine, but the loop is probably still necessary, without more information on OP's data. What if they don't want to count anything in `row[1:]`, for example.

Comment: btw congrats for your week rank. Newsflash: you can't beat Gordon so don't even try :) Once I did 350 in a day but still could not beat him.

Comment: Thanks D: I did 350 yesterday! That guy has monopoly on all his tags. I stopped bothering after I realised he was averaging 350+ per day. I had to spend 5 hours just to get to 350. It's a lot of effort.

Comment: either you get 20 upvotes or you get 20 accepted answers. Tough & frustrating (and shows you don't have a life or a job :)). There aren't always good questions... and you'll have to compete with me on the good ones, and on the duplicates that I close as fast as I can :)

Comment: I agree. I have to gently prod users to accept answers because it isn't basic nature to most of them, but I still feel bad doing it. Also, here's to friendly competition... :)

Comment: my theory on Gordon: some have sock puppets accounts, but he is more than 1 user sharing the same account

Comment: Hmm... does that break SO terms of service somehow? Not like it can be proven, but yeah.

Comment: Good idea. Link bookmarked. Actually, SO needs a "useful links" tab on the navbar that expands and lets people choose and paste useful links wherever.

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks everyone!

Comment: @nsring was it? You could choose to accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise category as a set; and remove the if block to add data into category,replace it with category.add

```
category = {}
group = columns.split("/")
group = group[-1].split(".")
if group[0] in ["data_1", "data_2"]:
    for row in data:
         category.add(row[0])
```

Hope this is clear